# typescript object possibly undefined no matter what I tried

Tags: typescript, canvas, next.js

I am using canvas to capture the cropped image. here is the function

```
export const getCroppedImg = (
  image: HTMLImageElement,
  crop: Crop,
  fileName: string
): Promise<Blob> => {
  let canvas: HTMLCanvasElement;
  let ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D;
  // I m using next.js
  if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
    if (crop) {
      canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
      const scaleX = image.naturalWidth / image.width;
      const scaleY = image.naturalHeight / image.height;
      canvas.width  =crop.width ? crop.width * scaleX : undefined;
      canvas.height =crop.height &&  crop.height * scaleY;
      ctx = canvas.getContext("2d") as CanvasRenderingContext2D;

      ctx.drawImage(
        image,
        crop.x * scaleX,
        crop.y * scaleY,
        crop.width * scaleX,
        crop.height * scaleY,
        0,
        0,
        crop.width * scaleX,
        crop.height * scaleY
      );
    }
  }
```

`crop.x, crop.y, crop.width crop.height`  causing ts error "Object is possibly 'undefined' ". I wrapped entire logic with `if(crop)`, i tried two diffent approaches

```
      canvas.width  =crop.width ? crop.width * scaleX : undefined;
      canvas.height =crop.height &&  crop.height * scaleY;
```

"canvas.width" and "canvas.height" warns that

```
"Type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.ts(2322)
```

Here is the Crop:

```
import { Crop } from "react-image-crop";

interface Crop {
        aspect?: number;
        x?: number;
        y?: number;
        width?: number;
        height?: number;
        unit?: 'px' | '%';
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take out the existing `crop.width` and `crop.height` into their own variables before checking them.

You also can't assign `undefined` to a `canvas.width`, or use `&&` to conditionally assign a value to the height - use `if` instead.

It doesn't look like proceeding with any of the logic makes sense if any of the `crop` properties are undefined (you wouldn't be able to draw the canvas or use `drawImage` properly), so throw an error or return early in such cases.

You also aren't returning a Promise, so remove the `Promise<Blob>` type.

```
export const getCroppedImg = (
    image: HTMLImageElement,
    crop: Crop,
) => {
    const { width, height, x, y } = crop;
    if (typeof window === "undefined" || !width || !height || !x || !y) {
        // Proceeding further would make no sense;
        // can't adjust canvas, or draw the image
        // return here, or throw an error or something
        throw new Error('Bad argument');
    }
    const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    const scaleX = image.naturalWidth / image.width;
    const scaleY = image.naturalHeight / image.height;

    canvas.width = width * scaleX;
    canvas.height = height * scaleY;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d") as CanvasRenderingContext2D;

    ctx.drawImage(
        image,
        x * scaleX,
        y * scaleY,
        width * scaleX,
        height * scaleY,
        0,
        0,
        width * scaleX,
        height * scaleY
    );
}
```

Comment: it worked. thank you. one more headache is gone

Answer (score 0):

You are saying in this line that canvas.width could be undefined:

```
canvas.width  =crop.width ? crop.width * scaleX : undefined;
```

so you can re work the logic so that is not the case.
That being said, sometimes you will know more than the TypeScript compiler so if you know that the value will never be undefined when you need to access it, you can assert the value.

```
canvas.width as number
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use optional fields on Crop interface?

Have you tried this?:

```
interface Crop {
    aspect: number;
    x: number;
    y: number;
    width: number;
    height: number;
    unit: 'px' | '%';
}
```

Comment: I did not wirte this, i imported it from the package. i should hava mentioned that